# Questions about Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I wrote the following calculation in R.
However, this is slow used in a number of "for loops" .

I tried to write similar calculations by using Rcpp .
But it was an error.

Please be correct my code.

```
# R
data <- matrix(1: 100, ncol = 5, nrow = 20)

Y <- 10
X <- Y - 1
Z <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(data) - X) 

for (i in 1:(nrow(data) - X)){
  Z[i, ] <- sum(data[i: (i + X), ])
} 
> data
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1   21   41   61   81
 [2,]    2   22   42   62   82
 [3,]    3   23   43   63   83
 [4,]    4   24   44   64   84
 [5,]    5   25   45   65   85
 [6,]    6   26   46   66   86
 [7,]    7   27   47   67   87
 [8,]    8   28   48   68   88
 [9,]    9   29   49   69   89
[10,]   10   30   50   70   90
[11,]   11   31   51   71   91
[12,]   12   32   52   72   92
[13,]   13   33   53   73   93
[14,]   14   34   54   74   94
[15,]   15   35   55   75   95
[16,]   16   36   56   76   96
[17,]   17   37   57   77   97
[18,]   18   38   58   78   98
[19,]   19   39   59   79   99
[20,]   20   40   60   80  100

> Z
       [,1]
 [1,] 2275
 [2,] 2325
 [3,] 2375
 [4,] 2425
 [5,] 2475
 [6,] 2525
 [7,] 2575
 [8,] 2625
 [9,] 2675
[10,] 2725
[11,] 2775



// Rcpp
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix myRcpp(NumericMatrix data, NumericVector Y) {
  int X = Y - 1;
  int i;
  int nrow = data.nrow();
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix Z();

  for (i = 0; i < nrow - X; i++) {
    Z[i] = Rcpp::sum(data( Range(i, (i + X)) , _ ));
  }  

  return (Z);
}
```

---

Postscript
Error message

---

```
sourceCpp("Rcpp/test.cpp")

g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/library/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c test.cpp -o test.o

test.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::NumericMatrix myRcpp(Rcpp::NumericMatrix, Rcpp::NumericVector)':

test.cpp:6:17: error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::sugar::Minus_Vector_Primitive<14, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >' to 'int' in initialization

test.cpp:12:8: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

test.cpp:12:51: error: no matching function for call to 'sum(Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Sub)'

test.cpp:12:51: note: candidates are:

C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sum.h:98:32: note: template<bool NA, class T> Rcpp::sugar::Sum<13, NA, T> Rcpp::sum(const Rcpp::VectorBase<13, NA, VEC>&)

C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sum.h:103:33: note: template<bool NA, class T> Rcpp::sugar::Sum<14, NA, T> Rcpp::sum(const Rcpp::VectorBase<14, NA, VEC>&)

C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sum.h:108:32: note: template<bool NA, class T> Rcpp::sugar::Sum<10, NA, T> Rcpp::sum(const Rcpp::VectorBase<10, NA, VEC>&)

test.cpp:14:14: error: invalid conversion from 'Rcpp::NumericMatrix (*)() {aka Rcpp::Matrix<14> (*)()}' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:67:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::Matrix(const int&) [with int RTYPE = 14, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]' [-fpermissive]
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the error you see?

Comment: I have appended an error message.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.
In the case of codeI showed using "sum" It would be solved in RcppRoll.
However, I sometimes want to use the "sd" instead of "sum".
RcppRoll is seems to not be able to apply the "sd" in more than one column.

Comment: If `rollapply` in zoo is sufficient then it can apply functions by column or across columns depending on the `by.column=` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a couple of errors. Mostly, I recommend disentangling complex expressions which *clearly* created compiler / template errors.

With the new code, I get:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/so_question.cpp")

R> # R
R> data <- matrix(1: 100, ncol = 5, nrow = 20)

R> Y <- 10

R> X <- Y - 1

R> Z <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(data) - X) 

R> for (i in 1:(nrow(data) - X)) {
+   Z[i, ] <- sum(data[i: (i + X), ])
+ } 

R> #data
R> #Z
R> 
R> myRcpp(data, Y)
 [1] 2275 2325 2375 2425 2475 2525 2575 2625 2675 2725 2775
R>
```

and the code is below -- I combined the R and C++ into one file.

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myRcpp(NumericMatrix data, int y) {
  int x = y - 1;
  int i;
  int n = data.nrow();
  Rcpp::NumericVector z(n - x);

  for (i = 0; i < n - x; i++) {
    Rcpp::SubMatrix<REALSXP> sm = data( Range(i, (i + x)) , _ );
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix m(sm);
    double s = Rcpp::sum(m);
    z[i] = s;
  }  

  return z;
}


/*** R
# R
data <- matrix(1: 100, ncol = 5, nrow = 20)

Y <- 10
X <- Y - 1
Z <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(data) - X) 

for (i in 1:(nrow(data) - X)) {
  Z[i, ] <- sum(data[i: (i + X), ])
} 

#data
#Z

myRcpp(data, Y)
*/
```

I usually do such sub-setting problems in RcppArmadillo ...

*Edit:* For completeness, in RcppArmadillo the loop body reduces to one line as we can use sub-matrix accessors -- here it is even simpler and we just pick rows -- over which we sum (twice) and (explicitly) convert to scalar.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec myArma(arma::mat data, int y) {
  int x = y - 1;
  int n = data.n_rows;
  arma::rowvec z(n - x);

  for (int i = 0; i < n - x; i++) {
    z[i] = arma::as_scalar(arma::sum(arma::sum(data.rows(i, i+x))));
  }  

  return z;
}
```

As Romain suggested, the extra copy in Rcpp has a cost we can measure once we get to larger matrices:

```
R> library(rbenchmark)

R> data <- matrix(1:1e6, ncol=50)

R> res <- benchmark(myRcpp(data, Y), myArma(data, Y))

R> res[,1:4]
             test replications elapsed relative
2 myArma(data, Y)          100   1.555    1.000
1 myRcpp(data, Y)          100   6.860    4.412
R>
```

Comment: Also please feel free to "upvote" (click on up arrow) the question, and, as the person who asked it, maybe also "accept it" (click on tickmark).  That is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: This however requires copy of the data into `m`. Would be better if `sum` knew how to handle matrix sugar expressions.

Comment: Sure, but the cost in run-time is small.  More compact expressions help, see the updated answer with its Armadillo one-liner solution.

Answer (score -1):

as I see it both you and the answer repeat the same calculation (the row sums) Y times for each row. So a vectorized solution,

```
data %>%
  rowSums %>%
  cumsum %>%
  {. - lag(., Y)}
```

(%>% from the package magrittr, the lag method from dplyr) should do what you want, and it is quite a bit faster than even Rcpp.

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  myArma(data, Y) 10.363077 11.633387 17.963248 12.233787 14.772540 131.67896   100   b
 vectorized(data)  3.172276  3.284239  5.492879  3.441609  4.664644  63.96084   100  a
```

You mentioned that you eventually want to use sd instead of sum, but even in that case caching the squared sums would save a lot of time.

```
data %>%
  {(. - mu)^2} %>%
  rowSums %>%
  cumsum %>%
  {. - lag(.,Y)} %>%
  divide_by( Y*NCOL(data) - 1 )
```

with mu being the group means that you get with the other solution.

A C++ implementation in that vein would of course be even faster than R but I don't think you can beat the code above for conciseness. :)

Ciao,
Stefan

EDIT: Depending on the structure and size of the data you might run into issues with subtractive cancellation from the cumsum minus lagged cumsum (i.e. if the cumsum gets 16 orders of magnitude larger than the single row sums you run out of significant digits). In that case you could replace that step with roll_sum from RcppRoll.

It's actually even shorter as a solution, I just have no experience with RcppRoll and can't say if there are issues or pitfalls

```
data %>%
  rowSums %>%
  roll_sum(Y)
```

Comment: Just too good to be true. Closest it could get in terms of performance might be`rowSums(roll_sum(data, Y))` where `roll_sum` is from `RcppRoll`. Your `vectorized` solution is computing a completely different thing.

Comment: admittedly `lag(.,Y, default=0)` is needed but then `all.equal(vectorized(data),myArma(data,Y))` returns `TRUE`. Where do you get the idea that we compute different things?

Comment: Apologies. I ran your code without dplyr loaded.  Nice solution. I see that performance is due to  efficiency of `cumsum`.  However, not all roll operations are `sum`, so it has only limited generalization. I doubt your `sd` example work.

Comment: Thank you.
Your solution also helpful.